# Captcha problem

Tags: captcha

I'm still having problems with captcha on tor. Now it is saying 'can't connect to the captcha' as well as 'Your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.' Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Basically, no. There's nothing that can be done if such services deny access to Tor users.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that message from Google Search. Unfortunately that's just the way it is for Google products. Bad guys on Tor sharing your exit node's IP get your IP blocked. Until Google differentiates between users in some way besides their IP, you'll rarely be able to use Google. It's this way for many other websites too.

Here's how you can send feedback to Google so they know you care:

Go to google.com outside of tor if possible, search for anything such as just "tor", go to the bottom of the page, click "Send feedback", and write "Google blocks my IP when I try to access Google Search over the Tor anonymity network." and hit "SEND". (Don't write too much or get angry, it will only slow down anyone who's just trying to tally up the votes.)

In the meantime, just change your default search provider to duckduckgo.com. If you saw that message trying to sign up for a gmail account, try protonmail.com, which is basically email for tor users (but not just tor users). They won't block you. As a side benefit, duckduckgo doesn't track you, and protonmail servers are physically incapable of reading your mail with the way they set up the crypto.

Also keep in mind, the more tor users there are, the less sites will be able to afford blocking tor IPs outright. So don't let this stop you from using tor.